# How can i send password using subprocess while logging in to unix box using ssh from windows using python

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to connect to unix box using subprocess module of python from windows machine.Please Note : Strictly want to use subprocess module(plz dont suggest pexpect,paramiko as i cant run them from windows to connect to unix as per my knowledge also have environment restricitons)
Here is my code that i have tried and i always get interactive keyboard authentication message with password prompt: i try to send password to that prompt but unable to do so.

```
import subprocess
cmd='plink -ssh username@hostname -pw password'
sp=subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdin=subprocess.pipe,stdout=subprocess.pipe,shell=False)
sp.stdin.write('password \n')
sp.stdin.flush()
error,out=sp.communicate
print error
print out
```

Using -pw in command doesnt work (have used one at a time- either -pw option or stdin.write), also have tried to stdin.write to console but couldn't do that also. I have some limitations on my execution environment too, also pexpect require termios which isnt present in windows

Comment: Are you willing to entertain other suggestions that do run on Windows and don't cause environment restrictions?

Comment: BTW, `shell=False` is (A) ignored on Windows, (B) not the flag you want when you pass in the command as a single string to `Popen`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes i am open to any suggestions using python internal modules through which i can connect to unix box without getting this messages and also please note i dont option to use private keys  to do passwordless login

Comment: I realize that your password is not actually "password" (or is it?), but the trailing space in `sp.stdin.write('password \n')` may be indicative of a typo

Comment: @MadPhysicist:no it is not i just type my password there, i've just used indicative string 'password' here

Comment: Can't remember if `pty` works on Windows or not. Otherwise you could do something similar to: https://github.com/Torxed/Scripts/blob/master/python/ssh_client.py

Comment: I'm no expert, but you may want to read through this section of the docs: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage-batch

Comment: You might need to set up ssh keys on the local machine/server, and you may need to use the -batch flag as well.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: dont have keys even from remote server and also no permissions to do so i.e copy my keys on server

Comment: If you can ssh in, you can copy your locally generated public key into your server's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. That is literally all it takes. And if you have `plink`, I am going to guess that you have putty keygen as well. The only possible problem is if the remote ssh is not set to accept public key authentication, but I doubt that could be the case.

Comment: It works in my tests when I give the password in the command line with `-pw pass`. So you should elaborate *Using -pw in command doesnt work* (remember, *doesn't work* means nothing and is helpless for other readers). Without more details, I just see this question as *unclear*.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: to elaborate more, i am able to use -pw one one unix box whereas on second box i cant use it and returns me Password: prompt. Not sure if there are any such settings which allow -pw to be accepted on one box and gives 'interactive keyboard authentication passsword:' on other

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on my Windows box to connect to a FreeBSD one:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = r'c:\path\to\plink -ssh user@machine -pw pass'
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdin.write(b'ls -al\nexit\n')
12
>>> p.stdin.flush()
>>> err = p.stderr.read()
>>> out = p.stdout.read()
>>> print(err)
b'Using username "user".\r\n'
>>> print(out.decode())
Last login: Mon Nov 20 17:16:18 2017 from xxx
... remaining of login message
$ ls -al
total 240
... listing of home directory
$ exit
```

`user`,`pass` and `machine` should be set per your own Linux or Unix box...

Comment: to elaborate more, i am able to use -pw one one unix box whereas on second box i cant use it and returns me Password: prompt. Not sure if there are any such settings which allow -pw to be accepted on one box and gives 'interactive keyboard authentication passsword:' on other

Comment: Is there a way where in i can accept output in unix box and enter password based on output, i have tried that thoufh but it doesnt work.Somethign like below `code` if sp.stdout == "Password" : sp.stdin.write('Password') `code`

Comment: @c-vang: The problem is likely to be server side. A sshd daemon can be configured to reject interactive keyboard authentication and only accept key based one. You should 1/ test interactively from a cmd windows if you can connect that second box 2/ ask the sysadmin for more details. But I'm afraid I cannot guess...